# Impossible to create a configuration file for an python application inside Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, configuration, configuration-files, configparser

I try to create a configuration file, where I can store constants.

Whenever I try with ConfigParser, I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/baun/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp        /__init__.py", line 511, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/home/baun/workspace/octopuscloud/s3/S3.py", line 138, in get
    test = parser.get('bucket', 'bucketname')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/ConfigParser.py", line 511, in get
    raise NoSectionError(section)
NoSectionError: No section: 'bucket'
```

simple.cfg:

```
[bucket]
bucketname: 'octopus_storage'
```

s3.py:

```
...
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read('simple.cfg')

...

# Get values from the config file
test = parser.get('bucket', 'bucketname')
...
```

How can I fix this?

===============================

The problem is fixed. The code was correct, but simple.cfg was in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 2):

```
[bucket]
bucketname= octopus_storage
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is fixed. The code and the config file was correct. The config file was in the wrong directory.